# Converting from Hexadecimal to Binary and vice versa. The Hard Way

Tags: java, binary, hex

I'm writing a code that should convert between binary, decimal, and hexadecimal. I have the binary and the decimal figured out but when I got to Hexadecimal I just got confused.

How would you do this conversion without using Integer.toHexString.

I understand that there is already a code that can do this for me in java, my confusion is how to I tell java to do it using hand conversion.

My idea was to create multiple if statements each explaining that 0 is 0000, or C is 1100 and so on for the others.

It would go through each character in the hexadecimal string and add together the binary values.

I feel like this is way to much code for what I'm being asked to do.

Unless this is the only way to do it, then I'll start doing it like that.

but if there is a pseudo-code that explains how to do this more effectively that would be appreciated.

extra info:

```
int hexDigit1A=(binaryDigit8%2)*8+(binaryDigit7%2)*4+(binaryDigit6%2)*2+(binaryDigit5%2)*1;
int hexDigit2A=(binaryDigit4%2)*8+(binaryDigit3%2)*4+(binaryDigit2%2)*2+(binaryDigit1%2)*1;
```

I understand that this converts a 4 bit binary number to its appropriate decimal, would this even be useful or is it just good for decimal.

Much thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achieved through a simple mapping function. When you do it by hand, you break the binary value into 4 bits correct? Then assign each "4-bits" it's own specific hexadecimal value. Your algorithm should go through your binary value, looking at each "4-bits" and determine the correct hexadecimal value to be applied.

This looks like a lab, so here's some super basic pseudo code.

```
Binary Value
Look at last 4 bits
Map to appropriate Hexadecimal Number
Look at next 4 bits, etc etc.
```

This should give you a good enough idea of what to for the Hexadecimal -> Binary conversion. Same idea!

Comment: I looked at your idea and it was the one i understood the best.

Instead of looking at the last 4 bits I looked at the first four bits and worked my way down deleting what I didn't need and it worked.

So thank you for the pseudo-code, it extremely helped.

Answer (score 1):

> My idea was to create multiple if statements each explaining that 0 is
>   0000, or C is 1100 and so on for the others.

Holy cow, that has to be like the worst idea ever.

The key to solving this problem is understanding what the numbers mean.

For example

A12C in hex can be expressed as

A*16^3 + 1*16^2 + 2*16^1 + C
or
10*16^3 + 1*16^2 + 2*16^1 + 12

From that you can then set up a while loop and do some div / mod kung fu to do conversions.

This way your conversions will work on any number baring max int limitations.

Answer (score 1):

All integers in modern computers are represented, in hardware, in binary.  Hexadecimal is a representation of a binary number in which each 4 bits is represented by one character 0-F.  So an integer that is

0100 1100

can also be represented as 4C in hex (76 in decimal).

There are two operations on integers that can help you out.  The first is the 'and' function, represented in java with a single ampersand ('&').  If you 'and' two integers, each bit position in one is anded with the corresponding bit position in the next one; therefore, if you 'and' with the binary number `0000 1111`, the result will be the same as the lowest 4 bits of the original number.  In our example, the result would be `0000 1100`.  (We call the 0000 1111 a 'mask' and say we are masking for the lower 4 bits or masking out the upper four.)

The second operation is the shift; one can shift right or left with >> and <<.

So if you have an integer and you want to output its hex equivalent, use a loop that:

1. masks for the 4 rightmost bits

   convert the result to 0-F and store somewhere (use the result as an index into an array of char!)

   shift the original to the right by 4 bits

and do that as many times as you have 4-bit groupings to convert.  The results you get will be in
reverse order, i.e., the first hex digit you get ends up on the rightmost side of your hex number.  If you want to adjust the algorithm to return the digits in forwards order, feel free!

A warning: negative numbers make this slightly more complicated, because shifting negative numbers tends to shift the 'sign bit'.  Rather than get into all that, I would get this down pat and understand all the concepts before I attempted to handle negative numbers.